# angular http infinite response handle

Tags: angular, http, response, infinite

Im trying to streaming an h.264 video format on the browser.

The video stream is made of custom format. so I have to handle the stream and convert it as standard video format in the browser side.

but there is a little problems

- the streaming api has an infinite response.[ header | body [ CUSTOM FORMAT (infinite size) ]] therefore, i can't handle it. (angular seems to do not support to handle http response before transfer done.)
- i can't add or change the streaming api. (can't updatable embedded device)
- i can't convert the stream in backend side. (video decode-encode spend a lot of server performance and bandwidth)

is that possiable to handle http response before it done?